# Error with FF4J configuration in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, ff4j

I am trying to use FF4J in my project, and i have added following dependencies to my build.gradle file.

```
org.ff4j:ff4j-spring-boot-starter:1.8.7,
org.ff4j:ff4j-web:1.8.7
```

I am observing below error during server startup after adding these dependencies:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'api' defined in class path resource [org/ff4j/spring/boot/web/api/config/FF4jSwaggerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket]: Factory method 'api' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lspringfox/documentation/service/Contact;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at com.adp.mnc.gcc.das.GCCDataAccessServiceSpringBootApplication.main(GCCDataAccessServiceSpringBootApplication.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket]: Factory method 'api' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lspringfox/documentation/service/Contact;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lspringfox/documentation/service/Contact;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
at org.ff4j.spring.boot.web.api.config.FF4jSwaggerConfig.apiInfo(FF4jSwaggerConfig.kt:57)
at org.ff4j.spring.boot.web.api.config.FF4jSwaggerConfig.api(FF4jSwaggerConfig.kt:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 22 common frames omitted
```

I guess this issue with version compatibility between FF4J and Springfox. The springfox version i am using is 2.4.0. I tried with multiple combinations, however, left with no clue.

Please check and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that current version of ff4j is using the Swagger 3.0.0 which seems not backward compatible with 2.4.0.

Multiple options:

- The spring-boot-starter should be used when you exposing the REST-API and webconsole. This component should be in standalone component without your code. Then in microservices you import ff4j library only with the store you need [sample code](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-1x/ff4j-voxxeddays-ticino-2018) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6PtQtOYhus)
- You update your spring-fox dependency.